# C# Newbie: Change Entity Framework DataBound DataGrid created with WPF drag-and-drop

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, populate, data-binding

I'm new to C# and I created a WPF GUI using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate (Windows 7 x64).

I used drag-and-drop technology to databind a datagrid to an SQL Server 2008 database table using Entity Framework technology.

This all works very well, despite my lack of C# skills.

I was able to hide columns using statements like:

```
dataGridInputEmails.Columns[0].Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

And I cleared the datagrid using:

```
dataGridInputEmails.Columns.Clear();
```

Now I want to populate the datagrid with a string that I created by reading in a text file and using:

```
string[] parts = slurp.Split(delimiters,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

But, I cannot figure out how to populate the datagrid.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dataGridInputEmails.ItemsSource = parts;
```

You shouldn't have to do `dataGridInputEmails.Columns.Clear();` first.

Comment: Thank you!  And what would parts be?  A datatable?

Comment: Oooh.  You me my string, "parts"

Comment: This seems to populate the datagrid with the length of each string in the array.  I've tried .ToString and .ToList but that doesn't work.

Comment: I should also mention that I am hoping to update the bound database by updating the datagrid.